# Mi intencion es hacer un bucle que recorrra una colección en mongodb para sumar todos los datos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, bucles, mongoose

Tengo una coleccion en mongo llamada "Servicios" y esta tiene los atributos de _id, usuario, hotel nombre y precio
y necesito traer todos los servicios con un find y sumar todos los precios para almacenarlo en una variable, alguien podría ayudarme?

```
var ServicioSchema = Schema({
usuario: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'usuarios' },
hotel: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'hoteles' },
tipoServicio: String,
precio: String
```

Comment: Porque el Precio es un String?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Las preguntas que exponen un problema sin al menos un intento de solución, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes optar por ocupar la potencia y optimización de los [aggregators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) de Mongo corriendo en su respectivo servidor.

Suponiendo que tu ODM es mongoose entonces harías algo así.

```
ServicioSchema.aggregate(
[{
      _id: "$_id",
          total: {
            $sum: "$precio"
          }
}],
(err, result) => {
      // Aquí haces lo que quieres con el resultado
})
```

Comment: Creo que le faltó el `$group`

Comment: Ese código de agregación está mal, por favor corrígelo. Saludos